# Best English translation of "conmoción"

Tags: traducción, definiciones

I was told the Spanish word *conmoción* refers to a strong feeling of shock or emotion shared by a group of people rather than an individual. It seems like English doesn't have a single word or phrase that describes this whole concept. What would be the best way to translate *conmoción* when translating something from Spanish to English?

Comment: I guess commotion or shock would be the best translations, be aware that, in medical context, conmoción means concussion.

Comment: @Laura: Shouldn't that be an answer? I'd vote it up.

Comment: I didn't think it was elaborated enough for an answer, but thanks for your "vote" :D

Comment: I would agree with @Laura's comment except that it should be `conmoción cerebral`. `Conmoción` alone means `shock`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=conmoci%C3%B3n):

> **conmoción** *sustantivo femenino*
>
> ( Med ) concussion
>
> (trastorno, agitación): el siniestro produjo una ~ en el país the disaster left the country in a state of shock;
>   la noticia produjo una ~ familiar the news shocked the whole family
>
> ( Geol ) shock

For your purpose I would go with "state of shock".